# Combining Round with ISNULL in a query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have searched around but have not managed to find an answer.  Is it possible to combine Round, Sum and isnull in an access SQL query?  I have been trying to code the following query:

```
ROUND(sum(iif(isnull(amount,0,amount))),2) as Amount
```

However I have had no success with the above or other variations.  Is my SQL flawed?

If my SQL is flawed, I'd be grateful if someone would be able to supply me with the correct syntax.

Comment: What was the nature of the lack of success?

Comment: What error is being returned?

Answer (score 2):

In Access `ISNULL()` takes a single argument and returns a boolean indicating whether the expression passed is null. In your query you have 3 arguments passed to `ISNULL`:

```
isnull(amount,0,amount)
```

To take it apart, first you need to check if amount is null:

```
IIF(ISNULL(Amount), 0, Amount)
```

Then add the `SUM`

```
SUM(IIF(ISNULL(Amount), 0, Amount))
```

Finally add the `ROUND`

```
ROUND(SUM(IIF(ISNULL(Amount), 0, Amount)), 2) AS Amount
```